# Pythona, create 2D Numpy array and append data vertically

Tags: python, sql

I have an SQL query that creates an array with 9 entries, I want to create a table with Numpy and append data as rows

The following code gives me an error

`ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)`

How can initialize the numpy array correctly, and append the array as a row to the table,

```py
sql_query = "select top 100 Passed, f.ID, Yld, Line, Location, Type, Name, ErrorID, Site from dw.table1 f join dw.table2 d on f.ID = d.ID where Type like '%test%'"
table_array = numpy.empty((0, 9))  
cursor.execute(sql_query)
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    table_array = numpy.append(table_array, row, axis=0)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: Don't repeatedly append to a numpy array in a loop. Since numpy arrays are contiguous blocks of memory, that requires the entire array to be copied over to new memory. Instead, _pre-allocate_ the amount of memory you will need, and _assign_ values.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I cannot simply append SQL row as a numpy array, had to fix it this way:

```
table_array = numpy.append(
    table_array, numpy.array([[row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]]]), axis=0)
```

Comment: The problem is not that it isn't an array. It's probably a list or other iterator that can be converted to an array automatically by numpy. The problem is that when this is converted to an array, it becomes a 1-dimensional array (since your list is just a list of values). This is what the error tells you.

Answer (score -1):

Don't repeatedly append to a numpy array in a loop. Since numpy arrays are contiguous blocks of memory, that requires the entire array to be copied over to new memory. This operation can slow down your loop significantly. Instead, *pre-allocate* the amount of memory you will need, and *assign* values when you get them from your query. When you do this, you can simply set one *row* of your array to the row you get from your query (assuming the type of all elements of your query is compatible with your numpy array)

```py
table_array = numpy.empty((100, 9))  # You know you're getting the top 100
row_num = 0
cursor.execute(sql_query)
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row and row_num < table_array.shape[0]:
    table_array[row_num, :] = row
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    row_num += 1

# If you want, you can then slice away the unfilled rows.
table_array = table_array[:row_num, :]
```